# SPARQL: Get all the entities of subclasses of a certain class

Tags: entity, instance, subclass, sparql

I've to get all the instances of a class C and subclasses (direct or indirect) of C, in SPARQL.

I can get all the direct subclasses of C in this way:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf :C .
  ?entity rdf:type ?subclass .
}
```

But I can't get the instances of an indirect subclass and neither any instance of C.

As I know (I've pre-calculated them) all the subclasses (direct and indirect of C), and I can build a dynamic query, is it possible build a query like the following one?

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
  ?entity rdf:type in <list>.
}
```

Thanks to everyone.

EDIT:

I've just solved it, even if in a not elegant way.

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
  { ?entity rdf:type :C }
  UNION { ?entity rdf:type :SubClass1 }
  UNION { ?entity rdf:type :SubClass2 }
  UNION { ?entity rdf:type :SubClass3 }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A better solution is to use property path expressions in SPARQL 1.1

This would be rewritten as:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
  ?entity rdf:type ?type.
  ?type rdfs:subClassOf* :C.
}
```

Comment: Depending on the triple store this might or might not work. Not all triple stores implement property paths expressions.

Comment: @msalvadores As an update, while there still may be older triple stores, property paths made it into SPARQL 1.1, so any triple stores that support the current standard will support property paths.

Comment: This is elegant, but will only work if all the (sub-)classes are in the default graph. Property paths do now do not work over named graph boundaries.

Comment: This answer is probably outdated? I had to use Robin Keskirarkka's syntax.

Answer (score 12):

Based on the [SPARQL 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypath-arbitrary-length) the proper way to do it would be:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
    ?entity rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* :C
}
```

Without support for property paths there is no way of expressing class hierarchies of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, these days, if the graph has basic RDFS inferencing (or better) available, you can do a direct query:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
    ?entity rdf:type :C
}
```

Technically, this means no property path required, but all relevant SPARQL query engines today are at least 1.1 if not RDF* compliant.

If using an engine that preprocesses the inference calculations and depending on the depth of the class hierarchy, this solution is generally faster than the previous solutions.

Comment: Right. Can you give some examples on "based RDFS inferencing" and "engines that preprocess the inference calculations" solutions?

Comment: @matthaeus An inferencing engine will precalculate all the inferred triples or calculate them at query time. This generally requires a config in a particular SPARQL engine for a separate graph to provide inferencing on a set of specified graphs using a specified inferencing "entailment"--the level of inferencing you want. Then, you use the graph like and with any other in your queries. For preprocessed inference, some engines will wait until its first query to calculate triples. Each implementation will have its own method for configuring an inference graph beyond the scope of discussion.