# Sparql query for children, grandchildren, .. of a class

Tags: sparql, owl, protege, protege4

I have an owl file I built in Protege. What is the sparql query which will select all the subclasses of a class and all the subclasses of those subclasses, so on and so on (Breadth First Search Sort of Manner)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.  The main idea is that you'd use a property path:  `select ?subclass where { ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf+ <some-particular-class> }`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might be answered by [Sparql query Subclass or EquivalentTo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21092246/1281433), but that question and its answer contain a lot more information that what you're asking for here.  You can't really enforce the search strategy (depth first vs. breadth first), but you can (sort of) order subclasses by their distance from the root, if there's a unique path from the root to the subclass.  First, let's get some sample data:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/q/23094361/1281433/>.

#            a
#          /   \
#         b     c
#        / \   / \
#       d   e f   g 

:b rdfs:subClassOf :a .
:c rdfs:subClassOf :a .

:d rdfs:subClassOf :b .
:e rdfs:subClassOf :b .

:f rdfs:subClassOf :c .
:g rdfs:subClassOf :c .
```

You can use a query like this to get the subclasses of `:a`:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/q/23094361/1281433/>

select ?subclass where {
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf* :a
}
```

```
------------
| subclass |
============
| :a       |
| :c       |
| :g       |
| :f       |
| :b       |
| :e       |
| :d       |
------------
```

The results include `:a` because we used the path `rdfs:subClassOf*`.  This is logically correct, since a class is a subclass of itself, but if you don't want `:a` included, you could use `rdfs:subClassOf+`, or you could filter out `:a` with `filter( ?subclass != :a )`.

In the case that there's a single path from the root to the subclass, you can count the intermediate nodes between them to determine their depth.  If you order by depth in this way, then you'll get your results in something like what a breadth first search would give you the following.  This technique is described in more detail in [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17523804/1281433) and [Calculate length of path between nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5198889/1281433).

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/q/23094361/1281433/>

select ?subclass (count(?intermediate)-1 as ?depth) where {
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf* ?intermediate .
  ?intermediate rdfs:subClassOf* :a .
}
group by ?subclass
order by ?depth
```

```
--------------------
| subclass | depth |
====================
| :a       | 0     |
| :b       | 1     |
| :c       | 1     |
| :d       | 2     |
| :e       | 2     |
| :f       | 2     |
| :g       | 2     |
--------------------
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this the other way around? From an object up the tree for every possible path like you have shown here? I would also like to know how to do this for an object that has multiple parents; e.g. from g to c to a, or g to b to a.

Comment: @ibrahimab Sure.  In SPARQL the reverse direction `:p` is just `^:p`. But you don't even need that necessarily.  Instead of `select ?subclass ... { ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf* ... rfds:subClassOf* :a . }` just swap the constant and the variable to: `select ?superclass ... { :mySubclass rdfs:subClassOf* ... rdfs:subClassOf* ?superclass }`.

Answer (score -1):

""SELECT ?x
WHERE {
?x rdfs:subClassOf* ?y.
}

Use the subClassof* for fetch all the subclasses and their subclasses too.

Comment: I think more information about what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried are needed.