# Output all parents under a particular root

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl

I have a structure that have different length from the root to leaf. I wish to output them into a list. I also wish all parents and grand parents are under market_segment. the maximum depth is 5 level, How do I bound the result to only Market_segment without going over to the parents of Market_segment. currenly this query will return parents of Market_Segment, if the path is shorter than 5.

```
PREFIX mdy: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/mdys.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?node ?parent ?gparent ?ggparent ?gggparent ?ggggparent
       WHERE {
                 ?node rdfs:subClassOf* mdy:Market_Segment                 
                   OPTIONAL {?node rdfs:subClassOf ?parent.
                    OPTIONAL {?parent rdfs:subClassOf ?gparent.
                    OPTIONAL {?gparent rdfs:subClassOf ?ggparent.
                    OPTIONAL {?ggparent rdfs:subClassOf ?gggparent.
                    OPTIONAL {?gggparent rdfs:subClassOf ?ggggparent.
                     }}}}}
}
```

Comment: Do either [Calculate the depth of subclass in the OWL ontology](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26115488/1281433) or [Sparql query for children, grandchildren, .. of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23094361/1281433) help?  They're similar questions.  You wouldn't get different variables (?parent, ?gparent, etc.) so easily, but you could get the depth of each node.

Answer (score 0):

Use inverse property paths:

```
PREFIX mdy: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/mdys.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?node ?parent
   WHERE {
             ?node ^rdfs:subClassOf* mdy:Market_Segment  .
             ?node ^rdfs:subClassOf ?parent         
}
```

See also
  http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths